# Was Yaakov's kidushin to Leah valid?

Tags: marriage, avot-patriarch-fathers, kiddushin-eirusin

It says in [Masechet Bava Batra 123a](https://themercava.com/app/books/metanav/15443):

> אָמַר לָהּ מִינַּסְבַתְּ לִי אָמְרָה לֵיהּ אִין מִיהוּ אַבָא רַמָאָה הוּא וְְלאֹ יָכְלַתְּ לֵיהּ אָמַר לָהּ מַאי רַמָּאוּתֵיהּ אֲמָרָהּ לֵיהּ אִית לִי אַחְתָּא דִקְשִישָא מִינַּאי וְְלָא מִנַּסְּבָא לִי מִקַּמָהּ אֱמָר לָהּ אָחִיו אֲנִי בְרַמָאוּת

> He(Yaakov) said to her (Rachel), Marry me. And she said to him, Yes, but my father's a deceiver, and you won't be able to stand up against him. He said to her, What's his deceit? She said to him, I have a sister who's older than me, and he won't allow me to be married before her. He said to her, I am his brother in deception.

The Gemara goes on a bit of a tangent and then says:

> מָסַר לָהּ סִימָנִין כִי קָא מְעַיְּילִי לָהּ לְלֵאָה סָבְרָה הָשְתָּא מִיכַסְּפָא אַחְתַּאי מְסַרְתִּינְהוּ נִיהֲלָהּ וְְהַיְינוּ דִכְתִיב וְַיְּהִי בַבקֶֹר וְְהִנֵּה הִיא לֵאָה מִכְלָל דְעַד הָשְתָּא לָאו לֵאָה הִיא אֶלָּא מִתּוֹךְ סִימָנִים שֶמָסַר לָהּ יַעֲקבֹ לְרָחֵל ומסרתה לְלֵאָה לָא הֲוְָה יָדַע לָהּ עֵד הַהִיא שַעְתָּא

> He(Yaakov) gave her(Rachel) certain identification signs. [To be able to communicate in the dark.] While Leah was being led into the bridal chamber, she [Rachel] thought, My sister will now be embarrassed, and so she gave her these signs. And this is what's written, 'And it came to pass in the morning that, behold, it was Leah,' [Bereishis 29:25] implying that until then she wasn't Leah! Rather, because of the identification signs that Yaakov had given to Rachel, who had entrusted them to Leah, he didn't know who she was until that moment.

If Yaakov really thought that he was marrying Rachel, was the Kiddushin valid?

Comment: ולא ה"ל קדושי לאה קדושי טעות דיעקב ודאי לא היה עושה בעילתו בעילת זנות והשתא אף אם היה מגרש אחת מהם לא היה יכול לקיים דבר שעתידה תורה לאסור ומן התורה איזה מהן שגירש הוה ליה השניה אחות גרושתו כיון דבאמת שניהם היו מקודשות לו ושניהם ודאי לא היה אפשר לו לגרש ודו"ק:

https://www.sefaria.org/Chidushei_Agadot_on_Sanhedrin.19b.2

Comment: Can you please post a translation as well? @אילפא